# remove square brackets from domino access services

Tags: java, json, rest, xpages

I want to access Domino data via the Domino Access Services (DAS) as REST provider in java e.g.

```
String url = "http://malin1/fakenames.nsf/api/data/collections/name/groups";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(new URL(url));
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(parser);
```

however, I notice DAS binds the JSON in square brackets:

```
[
  {
      "@entryid":"1-D68BB54DEA77AC8085256B700078923E",
      "@unid":"D68BB54DEA77AC8085256B700078923E",
      "@noteid":"1182",
      "@position":"1",
      "@read":true,
      "@siblings":3,
      "@form":"Group",
      "name":"LocalDomainAdmins",
      "description":"This group should contain all Domino administrators in your domain. Most system databases and templates give people in this group Manager access."
  },
 {
      "@entryid":"3-9E6EABBF405A1A9985256B020060E64E",
      "@unid":"9E6EABBF405A1A9985256B020060E64E",
      "@noteid":"F46",
      "@position":"3",
      "@read":true,
      "@siblings":3,
      "@form":"Group",
      "name":"OtherDomainServers",
      "description":"You should add all Domino servers in other domains with which you commonly replicate to this group."
  }
]
```

How can I easily get rid of these brackets?

Comment: square brackets represents array I guess? I'm not that familiar with JSON yet.

Comment: According to [this](http://jsonlint.com/) online validator, that is *valid* JSON. Removing the square brackets breaks it.

Comment: @Abhinav If you're unsure, guessing will only confuse OP more. However in this case you're correct. The square brackets indicate this is a JSONArray, with each element being a JSONObject

Comment: `[ ]` represent the collection/array of objects. If you remove them then you invalidate the structure, and also it would be hard to parse it back to objects using JSON parser.

Comment: how do you process the JSON? why do brackets bother you?

Comment: In order for the JSON to be valid, you need to to have a representation (JSON string) which can be parsed into a valid JS object. Using a tool like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) and paste in your code as-is, you'll see that it's valid, as your root object is an array. If you remove the square brackets, you have comma separated objects (curly braces) which are not a valid root JS object (if it were a single object, it would be). If you want to only return a single object, you should focus on that, but for multiple (your endpoint returns a collection) it will need to keep the square brackets.

Comment: the json data want to read is large (a company directory) so I read about the ability to stream the data with the jackson api. Examples I have read are without the opening and closing square brackets. With DAS my code seems to become invalid. I am new in Java and still struggling with common practices.

Comment: Perhaps the exmplanation here can help: https://quintessens.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/processing-json-data-from-domino-access-services-with-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you should leave them intact. You can parse theJSON array for example with Jackson.

find an example snippet below

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
...

String response = ... your posted string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    JsonNode taskIdsjsonNode = mapper.readTree(response);
    for (JsonNode next : taskIdsjsonNode) {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", "@entryid", next.get("@entryid"));
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", "name", next.get("name"));
    }
} catch (.... ) {
    // your exception handling goes here
}
```

**output**

```
@entryid: "1-D68BB54DEA77AC8085256B700078923E"
name: "LocalDomainAdmins"
@entryid: "3-9E6EABBF405A1A9985256B020060E64E"
name: "OtherDomainServers"
```

Comment: you are saying I should get the data first e.g. via `InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();` ? Or do promote another method?

Comment: @Malin I took `String` as input only to keep the example simple. In your amended example you read it directly from th URL. From my point of view there is no `prefered best` way as input. Choose the one which solves your problem in the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are not nasty but a correct notation. To access the contens just use [0] in your client side script or with your JSON parser in Java you like.

Comment: you are saying I should get the data first and then alter it e.g. via `InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();` ? Or do promote another method?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the explanation here can help:

https://quintessens.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/processing-json-data-from-domino-access-services-with-jackson/

Basically you establish a call to DAS via the Jersey client and then you parse the json via Jackson library to a map in java.

During the parsing process you can define which values you want to parse and transform them.

Take a look at the Person class...